# Загрузка google maps при скролле

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Как сделать так, чтобы гугл карты загружались на сайт после того, как пользователь совершил какие-либо действия(например, проскроллил страницу) или сразу после загрузки остальных компонентов?

Comment: для начала определитесь для какого именно действия, а то для всех возможных вариантов, очень много писать кода нужно

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich для скролла

Comment: @DoctorGun, а что если вам немного изменить задачу? Вы можете загружать их всегда, а вот **показывать**, при скролле. Изменять DOM всегда проще, чем загружать внешние источники на лету, да и пользователи не будут ждать загрузки.   Смотрите в сторону события scroll [jQuery .scroll() (англ.)](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/), [native JS .onscroll (рус.)](https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll)

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, какая разница после какого? Он спрашивает, как их загружать из скрипта. Хочет таким образом ускорить загрузку сайта - сначала грузятся все его скрипты и страница полностью работоспособна, потом начинает загружаться карта.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, так себе идея - вероятно, она не соответствует целям автора вопроса.

Comment: @Qwertiy тут двояко смысл можно понимать. Я например понял вопрос типа как обработчик событий повесить..

Comment: @Qwertiy, ничего из сказанного вами в вопросе не было. По тому как это совсем другой вопрос. Цель автора загружать карту при скролле. Что не слишком целесообразно.

Пожалуйста покажите мне где именно говорится про оптимизацию, загрузку из скрипта и вообще все то о чем вы говорите.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, я так его понимаю :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы правы, мне нужно оптимизировать загрузку сайта.